# How to generate user Id for IM application in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am authenticating a user in my windows phone using live sdk.now I want to generate user I'd for that particular email login the back end.is there any standard or Apis within wp sdk which I can use To generate userid for that particular email login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs to generate User IDs. This is completely up to you on how to implement this. You can simply use their email address as their User ID since it will be unique for each person. Or you can generate a random GUID using `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

If you want to tie the user to their device then you can use the device unique Id using `DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId").ToString()` However note this value will never change so you will always want to check both email and the device Id in case ownership of device is transferred.

Comment: I think I will better go with email address only to uniquely identify user on any device.